# (index):4918 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I keep getting this error and it makes no sense at all!!!

site is working just fine, and the error seems to be meaningful for the normal flow.

i keep trying to delete all-white spaces and the error just scales up in my files.

it is always there and there is nothing like a "<" or any other character... it's just a red cross that says nothing!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeTdm.png)

Comment: Stop to be troll the guy is new and need help!

Comment: @Alonso, you cumulate negative valoration because your question is not clear at all, check this guide, it will help you to better ask the next time, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Tienes comentarios en español!!! primera vez veo eso en shopify :P

I'm sure you has a typo even an script organization typo (you use something before it is charged) at the same time you has a lot of external stuff so hard to say without the code if the problem is on your end, conflict between aps or inside one of the apps.

The best thing to do is download your site using [theme kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) and use vscode or other dev program you like to read the code. Install the linters helpers and other extensions and the bug will disappear by magic.

Comment: I see the domain of your site on the picture you post from the devtools, after that I visit your site and check the bug you has, my response is very general and I hope it help you to catch this bug